# .htaccess redirects not working on localhost

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, localhost

I have the following `.htaccess` which is supposed to open `/index.php` for **ALL requests**, regardless of whether the requested folder or file exists:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule . index.php [END]
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work on my localhost:

- `http://localhost:9000/file` -> opens `/index.php` (GOOD)
- `http://localhost:9000/folder/file` -> opens `/index.php` if `/folder/` doesn't exist (GOOD)
- `http://localhost:9000/folder/file` -> "Not Found" if `/folder/` exists (BAD)
- `http://localhost:9000/file.php` -> opens the file if it exists and gives a "Not Found" if it doesn't exist (BAD)
- `http://localhost:9000/folder/file.php` -> opens the file if it exists and gives a "Not Found" if it doesn't exist (BAD)

My localhost is running on macOS via `php -S localhost:9000` in Terminal.

Comment: How about using `RewriteRule ^  index.php [QSA,END]` once here?

Comment: Exactly the same result

Comment: Could you please confirm if your htaccess and index.php are residing in same path?

Comment: Yes they are 100%. They're in a folder called `/www/`, which I `cd` to before running `php -S localhost:9000`

Comment: ok, one more clarification, do you have any other rules apart from these shown ones? Please confirm once.

Comment: No, the two lines in my original post are the only lines in my `.htaccess`. So everything else must be my environment's default behaviour. FYI, I don't believe I have changed anything regarding php's default behaviour

Comment: Any other htaccess before this path is present?  Asking for safer side here to remove all doubts =.

Comment: There is none :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments to the question I understand that you are not using an apache http server for this, but rely on the http server built into php itself (`php -S localhost:9000`).

Please note that ".htaccess" style files are *apache* configuration files. I doubt that the builtin server has any idea about the purpose of those files ...

Instead that builtin server offers a feature to route all requests through a router script:

```
php -S localhost:9000 index.php
```

This is documented under "Example #3 Using a Router Script" in https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: Actually, now nothing works within my files, like a simple `<img src="img.jpg">`... I guess because that too is redirected to `src="index.php"`? Is there way to fix this?

Comment: You can handle that in the router script. That actually is the purpose of such script.

Comment: Oh sweet. Just for anybody reading, I just had to prepend the following to my index.php: `if(preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|css|js)(.*?)$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) { return false; }`